# How could I write a function allowing users to edit a 3D object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling

I am writing an **Android App** which allows users to **DIY their phone cases** and then export them to .stl/other **3D printing** format.

There is a function:

1. User ***inserts a photo***(*a logo/pattern*).
2. my app will **draw the corresponding pattern** onto the **back of a phone case**. For example, lets say the logo is an apple. The user can choose "Hollow" or "Convex&Concave" mode.

**"Hollow"** is sth like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSUgr.jpg)

**"Convex&Concave"** is sth like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMo15.jpg)

The case doesnt have any pattern on itself(plain one). So this function will draw the image onto it.

My question is:

1. How to write an **editting function**(allow user to edit 3D object in
   run-time) in **Unity3D(C#)**? Are there any built-in functions which could help me achieve this?
2. Or do I need to **import plugin** from other software(***3ds max, CAD***) in order to perform this function?

I am not sure if I have made my problem clear enough. If you want more details, just feel free to ask. Thank you very much!

Image source:
1. dhresource
2. tvc-mall.com

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you want with C# in your case if i got it correct. Position of the logo, size, any other patterns if you like to add etc. I suggets you should do this tasks one by one. Create a UI panel, add 2 text box, first one is for x, second one is for y. Get this parameters and use it as your logo's position. You can add other properties in to the panel so user can change it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :).